# Mass retag request for all [c++0x] tagged questions with [c++11]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Since the approval of C++11 last year, many questions have been retagged from [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). However, there's still a lot left.

[image: C++0x]

Can we have a mass retag?

Answer (score 5):

In general this is a good idea, however care needs to be taken with questions which genuinely are C++0x and not C++11, e.g. concepts.

Comment: Yes, and there's also this question about when C++0x will be finished, from Howard. That's another question that's genuinely tagged [tag:c++0x].

Comment: @Xeo: IMO, that should be closed as "too localized". That answer won't help anyone anymore.